# How can I apply DeferredDeliveryTime to appointment invite in oulook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have borrowed some code to apply a delay to the sending of an email out of outlook but when I generate an appointment invite this code does not apply and the mail item generated stays stuck in the outbox.

I would welcome any suggestions!
Simon

This is the code I have thus far:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal olItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim response As Integer
response = MsgBox("WHOA - delay sending?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
If response = vbYes Then
olItem.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 10, Now)
Else: MsgBoxResult = vbNo
olItem.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 2, Now)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Do you get any errors in the `ItemSend` event handler?

Answer (score 0):

The [MeetingItem.DeferredDeliveryTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem.deferreddeliverytime) property allows setting a Date indicating the date and time the mail message is to be delivered. But it doesn't prevent items from sending. The item will be put to the outbox folder and sent out when it is scheduled.